# MySQL starting 2 processes that can't be used

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am running MySQL on CentOS. When I attempt to start it gives an error but in the background 2 processes are started:

Stop:

```
$ sudo service mysqld stop
[sudo] password for arifu: 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  mysqld.service

$ ps -aux | grep mysql
arifu    20332  0.0  0.0 112620   744 pts/0    S+   13:08   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Start:

```
$ sudo service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Logs:

```
$ systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: deactivating (final-sigterm) (Result: exit-code)
Process: 17465 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 17443 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
        └─17468 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid...



$ ps -aux | grep mysql
mysql    17798  0.0  0.0  53032  3620 ?        Ss   13:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
mysql    17800 89.6  6.7 39831592 3308524 ?    Rl   13:03   0:02 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
arifu    17826  0.0  0.0 112620   744 pts/0    S+   13:04   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

None of these can be used:

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p mysql
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I managed to trace the problem to wrong configuration - `join_buffer` & `malloc-lib`:

```
join_buffer=256M
malloc-lib=/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
```

I had copied these when I migrated from MySQL 5.6 but it appears they no longer work for 5.7

Answer (score 1):

The name of the first one is `join_buffer_size`.  And `256K` (*not* `M`) has been the default since 5.6.6.  Using `256M` is likely to blow out RAM all too easily.  This would either slow down mysqld (due to swapping) or crash it (out of memory).

I don't know about the `.so`, but I would certainly suspect it.

As for 2 processes -- On some Operating systems, several processes, the number based on some configuration values, probably `thread_cache_size` and `max_connections`, plus usage patterns.